# I've enabled dark mode, where's my hat?

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

I saw this hat:

[image]

My first reaction was, "SO has a dark mode?!" So I hunted out the setting and turned it on. I didn't like it. So I pretty much immediately turned it off again. Where's my hat dagnamit?! {shakes fist at sky}

[image]

Comment: Why didn't you like dark mode? What was wrong with it?

Comment: How do your eyes not burn out with light mode?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hats are not awarded instantly; your account is added to a queue that is processed when next there is a bit of time on the server.

Stack Overflow is a busy place and there are many, *many* other users trying out for hats so it may take some time (up to ~1 hour in some cases) to award hats.

Note that this specific hat will not be awarded if you are not using Dark Mode by the time the batch runs. Try again with Dark Mode enabled (set to *Dark*) and leave it on until you earned the hat. Just wait an hour or so (should be less but best be sure).

I normally have Dark Mode set to *System setting*; I had switched it to *Dark* to earn the hat.

Comment: I did this yesterday

Comment: @Liam what setting did you use? System or Dark?

Comment: "Dark" so the one to the far right. I didn't have it on for long TBF, but I've tried it once yesterday and again this am

Comment: I can see you've enabled your hat... :(

Comment: @Liam I thought it apt :-) It may be that Cody is right and that a bug may be causing this hat to only be awarded if you also have an account on one of the other language SO accounts. I have a few of those as we sometimes coordinate with other site mods about cross-site behaviour. I earned mine here however.

Comment: @Liam I changed my setting to “Dark” again when I write my previous comment, and have now been awarded the hat on several other SO language variants that I didn’t have it on (I initially earned it  here only). You need to have it on and *leave it on* until awarded.

Comment: I can confirm that switching to dark mode and leaving it on until the hat is awarded works.

Comment: Thank you for this very useful answer! I enabled dark mode in order to get the hat and I really don't like it, but now I know I'll need to wait a while before disabling it.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem earlier. I don't normally like or use Dark Mode, but *who doesn't like hats*?! So, upon seeing that there was a hat to be earned by enabling Dark Mode, I promptly went to my profile and turned on Dark Mode. With Dark Mode enabled, I surfed around Stack Overflow, interacted with a bunch of questions, voted on some stuff, edited some stuff, etc. After I felt like I had paid a sufficient amount of tribute to the Dark Mode, I went to see if my hat had arrived. It hadn't.

Now, hats are awarded as a scheduled task, and Stack Overflow is *huge*, so I thought I might just need to wait a while. Even after waiting over an hour, I still hadn't received the hat, though.

I turned Dark Mode back off and went about my business.

Later, in a flash of inspiration, I finally figured out a workaround to earn my hat: **create an account on one of the non-English Stack Overflow sites** (in my case, Stack Overflow in Spanish). After creating this account and enabling Dark Mode, I earned the hat almost instantly. Since I can't speak Spanish, I floundered around for a bit trying to figure out how to delete my account on that site, and eventually figured it out by doing a side-by-side comparison with the English Stack Overflow profile options.

I suspect there's a bug here affecting awarding of the Flashlight hat to users with established Stack Overflow accounts who don't normally use Dark Mode. I previously noted this odd behavior in [a comment on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357920/earned-a-hat-on-the-wrong-site/357923#comment1195753_357923).

Looking now, I see that I *have*, in fact, earned the hat on English SO, so I don't know if it was just a caching/latency problem all along, or if earning it on a non-English SO site was required to spur things along.

Comment: I normally use Dark Mode but with the “System” setting. I switched it to just “on” but then did earn it on SO first though I also have a Spanish SO account (already had an account there and know enough Latin-based languages to find my way around).

Comment: Yaakov already confirmed that [the "System" setting doesn't count for the purposes of the hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357963/flashlight-hat-not-awarded-with-theme-set-to-system-setting-when-dark-mode-e), so that makes sense. And earning it on the Spanish site first also makes sense, because the activity there is much lower than English SO. Although I see you did eventually manage to earn the hat on English SO. I never did. I would say it was just my impatience, but I've earned other hats on SO *much* faster than a full hour.